# How to read npm data using python

Tags: python, rest, npm

I'm trying to write a project to access npm pages for a project and 'scrape' some data off of a given page. I've been recommended to check REST APIs and stuff like, but I'm not too familiar with them and I'm not really sure what to do.  As an example, with [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/handlebars) link, I would like to be able to retrieve all of the information highlighted in the screenshot below:[image]

Answer (score 2):

Accessing this content through an API is indeed the right solution.
You could use the open source project [npms.io](https://npms.io/).

You can use its API to make advanced queries, or get information individually for a specific package.
For handlebars, you could do it this way in Python:

```python
import requests
import json

url = "https://api.npms.io/v2/package/handlebars"
resp = requests.get(url)
package_data = json.loads(resp.content)
```

You could then access the information you want in `package_data`.
Depending of the needs of your project, you could explore npms.io's API documentation to optimize your queries.

Comment: I tried this in my code, but I keep on getting an error when trying the json.loads(response.content) line.  The error I get is: 'json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)' but I cant seem to figure out why.  Is there some way I should format the string differently?

Comment: It could be many things, like an empty response body.
This goes beyond the scope of the question and it is quite hard to determine the issue without more context.